# Azure Cosmos DB .NET v3 Linq WHERE condition empty result

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Whenever I add `.Where` condition, my resultSet is always empty.

Below is my code:

```
 QueryRequestOptions queryRequestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions()
            {
                PartitionKey = partitionKey
            };

using (FeedIterator<Item> resultSet = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Item>(requestOptions: queryRequestOptions)
                .Where(x => x.IsContainer) // without this, I am able to return all the items
                .ToFeedIterator())
            {
                while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (var item in await resultSet.ReadNextAsync())
                    {
                         // print here
                    }
                }
            };
```

How can I apply filtering condition using Linq?

Comment: If you use the same code, but instead of `ToFeedIterator()` you do `ToString()`. What is the resulting `string`? and if you manually run that from the portal on your database after adding the partition in your filter expression. Do you get any results? This code looks fine as far as I can tell; Maybe you haven't set the `JsonPropertyAttribute` for your property or it contains a typo?

Comment: What is `IsContainer`? A boolean property on the documents? What is the casing on the actual saved documents?